# How to move last page to first page using UIPageControl in iphone

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I want to implement page sliding as in iphone google+ application's stream.

So i want to return to first page when we swipe last page. I tried this using `UIPageControl` but I can't do this.

So please give me any idea.

Comment: You don't have to use so many `.` in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried pageControl I assume you have downloaded Apple's example project of Page Control if you have not  ==> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

```
// Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
pageControl.currentPage = page;
```

You are going to see this part of code to handle the page number and the next page. and loads prev current and next pages at once. Try implementing page calculating mechanism with a % operator to you total page number. Therefore as soon as you arrive last page your next calculation will give you 1. So the next page will be set to one as soon as you swipe.

EDIT:
***By the way this only changes the page indicator, you should also load the page views according to this page calculation. Because they are not automatically binded to indicator***.

You can see how powerful a mod operator is :)

Comment: Ya i done this but i am not getting smooth scrolling from last to first its moving suddenly

Comment: Yeah that is because for smooth scrolling it caches (page-1) (page) and (page + 1) But in this case you only load page 1 directly not with 6 and 2 therefore what you can do is you use modular for totalPageNumber-1 and you check the condition if page+1 is the last page and then you make page+1 = 1 by using modular operator again. In that case page-1 loads =>5 page loads => 6 and page +1 loads =>1 

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for giving some idea.Tell me if any other idea if you have to implement this.

Comment: I tried this in an intern unfortunately I don't have the code with me to show you an example but it worked. Hope you good luck!.